# MODIFY STATEMENT SAS - EXPECTING NAME ERROR

Tags: date, sas, format, dataset

I'm trying change the format of column using datasets whith modify statement:

````
PROC DATASETS LIBRARY= EU.ARRECADACAO_CONTAS_DOCINV;
MODIFY EU.ARRECADACAO_CONTAS_DOCINV;
FORMAT DTPAGTO DDMMYY10.;
FORMAT DTVENCTO DDMMYY10.;
QUIT;```

What am i doing wrong?

Tks.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note change to LIBRARY= and MODIFY

```
PROC DATASETS LIBRARY= EU;
   MODIFY ARRECADACAO_CONTAS_DOCINV;
   FORMAT DTPAGTO DDMMYY10.;
   FORMAT DTVENCTO DDMMYY10.;
   QUIT;
```

Comment: Thank you, @data_null_!